# How to select records with opposite values

Tags: sql

I have two tables -

```
Flight with fields Flight_No (PK), Flight_Name, Total_Seats and Available_Seats.
```

The second table -

```
Schedule has fields - Schedule_Id(PK), Source, Destination, Date_of_Travel, Flight_No and Travel_Time.
```

The problem is that can I write a query to list all Flight numbers where source and destination of a flight are the destination and source of another flight.

I dont know where to start

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to join the same table twice with an alias like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Schedule s1
JOIN Schedule s2
ON s2.Flight_No = s1.Flight_No
AND s2.Source = s1.Destination
AND s1.Date_of_travel = s2.Date_of_travel
```

Comment: I think 'ON s2.Flight_No = s2.Flight_No' must not be there.

Answer (score 0):

could be trying using a join with schedule for both source and destination

```
select a.Flight_No, a.Source, a.destination 
from Schedule a 
inner join  schedule b  on a.source = b.destination  
inner join  schedule c on  a.destination = c.source
```